# Pulling from a previous Git repo from a teammate

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have been working with a series of classmates on a project. An accident caused me to make a mess of my own repository to the point where it's unusable, and I'm not sure when the issue occurred. I believe it's easier to simply empty out my repository, and pull from the latest of my classmates' commits, but when I do this, nothing happens. My repository is still blank.

We all have forked from the teacher's base repository, and we're using Git Extensions, since we're all new to Git (but required to use it for the class.)

[image]

I'm trying to revert to Shade's commit earlier in the day entitled "Updated Game," but I don't know how to go about that. How do I go about this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will rapidly get frustrated with the GUI when trying to do anything but the simplest stuff with Git.  This is one of those times where you do something more complicated, and you need to use the terminal ;).  Run:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard Shade/master
```

Note that *this will destroy any uncommitted work*.

Now `master` will point at the commit that `Shade/master` is pointing to.  This is the answer to your question.  But!  There is a catch that you should consider.  By restting your `master` behind `origin/master`, you've created a situation where you can't push to `origin/master` anymore, because `origin` would reject the non-fast-forward push.  What you have to do is "dummy merge" `origin/master` into your local copy, like this:

```
git merge --ours origin/master -m "Fix botched work"
```

The `--ours` flag discards any changes in the other branch that might otherwise have been merged in.  Now you can push without `origin` complaining.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Before you try any of this, make sure you can't just do `git reset --hard HEAD` to reset to the current commit, restoring all the files in your working directory.  It sounds like you might have just nuked the working directory, no amount of `git pull` will make Git reinstate them.

Comment: Although resetting the head didn't do the job, it was a good suggestion! Making a new branch fixed the issue I was having with the repo, but it seems the real issue that I'm having is seated in Gradle, not just having missing files in my repo. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use git log to get the commit hash like 43566df6a26a31a2d44ad102ffa241a0ab55edde. You can use git checkout  and then git checkout -b  to make a new branch from that point. You can also delete the old branch with git branch -D  git branch -m supports moving (renaming) the new branch.