# How to replace local repository with a previous git commit

Tags: git

I would like to replace my current local repository with an older git commit that i have pushed, is this possible? also i am the only person using this remote repository so messing with other peoples work is not an issue.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "replace my current local repository"? Something like `git reset --hard <old-commit>`?

Comment: i would like my local repository to change, to self delete any changes and become an older version that i have committed and pushed before

Comment: i tried git reset --hard <old-commit> and it changed master and head to the commit i want but how to i know import that and make it override my current local repository(git noob here if thats not obvious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ran `git reset --hard <old-commit>` as nwellnhof suggested, it should move the current branch to the commit you specified (`reset`) and snap your working directory back to the state recorded in the commit (`--hard`).

Anything you aren't tracking will still be around, which might be why you're confused.  You might try [running `git clean`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/removing-untracked-files-from-your-git-working-copy) if you're sure of what you're doing.

Also, your remote(s) will complain when you try to push again, because it won't be a fast-forward push.  If you're the only one who has access, you can just use `--force`.  If not, then see [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073559/pulling-from-a-previous-git-repo-from-a-teammate/23074355#23074355) for a better approach.